# Buttons are being unable to click

Tags: android, button

I'm having a problem with my buttons which is being unable to click, I don't know why is that. Could someone help/tell me please?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
package com.example.randallinho.saling_wika;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RecordModule extends Activity {

Button SpeakBtn, StopBtn;
private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
private String outputFile = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recordmodule);

    SpeakBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SpeakBtn);
    StopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopBtn);

    StopBtn.setEnabled(false);
    SpeakBtn.setEnabled(false);
    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";

    myAudioRecorder= new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

    SpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                myAudioRecorder.start();
            }

            catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SpeakBtn.setEnabled(false);
            StopBtn.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    StopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myAudioRecorder.stop();
            myAudioRecorder.release();
            myAudioRecorder = null;

            StopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            SpeakBtn.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    SpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException,SecurityException,IllegalStateException {
            MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                m.setDataSource(outputFile);
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                m.prepare();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            m.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_record_module, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have no idea why my buttons are being unable to click, someone please lend me a helping hand.

Comment: your logic is not correct, at least enable one button initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you yourself did it.

```
StopBtn.setEnabled(false);
SpeakBtn.setEnabled(false);
```

you are disabling it and enabling it in `onClick` of that `Button`, how `onClick` will be called if `Button` is disable?

Atleast `enable` one button, so that other code will get execute

Comment: This helped. I forgot to enable that SpeakBtn, and thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

Set one of your button to true because you are disabling button.

```
SpeakBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SpeakBtn);
StopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopBtn);

StopBtn.setEnabled(true);
SpeakBtn.setEnabled(false);
```

so your code will get execute.

Answer (score 0):

onClick of button will work only when button is enabled. Enable your button first where you want to use onClick of your button. 
Remove last two lines from below

```
SpeakBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SpeakBtn);
StopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopBtn);

StopBtn.setEnabled(false);
SpeakBtn.setEnabled(false);
```